# What happens when I flag something on Lemmy (report comment moderation)?

Tags: untagged

What exactly happens when I report a comment or post on Lemmy? Who receives it, and what actions can they take? How can I track the progress of the report?

Unlike most centralized websites like Facebook, Reddit, Twitter, etc., Lemmy is federated. So if I'm browsing content on a community on a "remote" instance (a Lemmy server that's distinct from the one where my user account is registered), it's not clear exactly where my "report" will go.

Does it go to the admins of "my" instance? Does it go to the admins of the "remote" instance where the content was originally published? Does it go to all of the admins of all of the instances with users that are "linked" to this instance or have users who subscribe to the community where the content was originally published? Does it go to just one random mod of the community's moderators? Or does it go to all of the community's moderators? Does it go to any other moderators?

And what does it look like from the admin/moderator's side? Does it give them a notification about the flagged content? What actions are they presented with for each flagged content? And, if there are multiple recipients of this flagged content, how does it change once just one of them takes an action on the flag?

What actually happens when I click the flag to "report" some post or comment on Lemmy?

Comment: This looks to be the first question tagged [tag:lemmy] in Web Applications Stack Exchange. Would you mind to suggest a tag wiki so other might understand how this tag should be used and other relevant information about this web app that help to make high quality posts?

Comment: Also, the question looks to require more focus (it has too many question statements).